# Jekyll broken posts links in github-pages

Tags: url, jekyll, github-pages

I am build my jekyll page and i just uploaded to gh-pages. When i click on my post links i get a 404 error here is my setup.

**_config.yml**

```
baseurl: ""
url: "bousis.github.io/blog"
permalink: /blog/:title
```

here is the code in the index

```
<ul class="posts">
    {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li> 
     <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    <span class="right date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

i have my `baseurl: ""` because this is the only way could get my css to load. removing the leading `/` from the head.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

here is my folder tree
[folder tree][1](https://github.com/bousis/blog)

what i want to achive is be able to have something like this in my url

```
bousis.github.io/blog/welcome-to-jekyll to link to my post
```

or it would be perfect if i could get

```
bousis.github.io/
```

as index

and `bousis.github.io/welcome-to-jekyll` for my posts

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `bousis.github.io` repository and push you jekyll sources in the `master` branch.

You're _config.yml is then :

```
baseurl: ""
url: "bousis.github.io"
permalink: /:title
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to David Jacquel's correct answer, should you want to achieve the previous `bousis.github.io/blog/welcome-to-jekyll` style links, you are almost correct, **you would just need to set the `baseurl` to `blog`**, instead of the entire address. While your `url` will have the value of `bousis.github.io`.

So you would have these values:

```
baseurl: blog/
url: "bousis.github.io"
permalink: /:title     #this actually works now, it didn't for me last time, not sure why
```

After which you need to follow the [tutorial](https://pages.github.com/) at GitHub Pages for a project site, where you **create a repository named `blog` with a `gh-pages` branch.** (Or if you already have a repository, just create a gh-pages branch), GitHub will give you a url in the format of `username.github.io/name-of-repo`

And then finally go ahead and push your Jekyll site to that branch in that repo.

*Note: `pretty` permalinks will display posts with the date as well, if you prefer that.*

A good reference on using baseurl can be found on [this blog post](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/) titled : Clearing up Confusion around Baseurl - Again. And this write up on [how to handle permalinks in Jekyll](https://davidtuite.com/posts/how-to-manage-permalinks-in-jekyll).

It is recommended to set your own permalinks for non-post pages, such as if you have an `about` page, make sure to explicitly set the permalink as `/about` to avoid any possible collision if you have a `post` named `about`. This shouldn't happen if you keep note of it, but might save you headaches in the future if you somehow create a post titled `about`.

Comment: Ok i got it working. now my site is [bousis.github.com/myblog][1]
i have the `baseurl: /myblog` and `permalink: /:title`.
this is setup on a `gh-pages`. What i want now is to set the default url of the site to `bousis.github.io/` without the `/myblog` i know i have to move my files to master branch or something like that but i don't know how i am a newbie. If you have any ideas please help me. Thank you guys.

  [1]: http://bousis.github.io/myblog